# prevent quartz scheduler to rollback

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

i am new on this way.I am using quartz scheduler in my application. Quartz 2.x
Its working fine, but when exception occur. it rollback data.So i want to stop auto rollback.

below is qurtz properties file

```
#    Configure Main Scheduler Properties

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyClusteredScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO


#    Configure ThreadPool   

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 25
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5

#   Configure JobStore

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass =   
org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_

org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000
```

## Configure Datasources

```
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL =     
jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase?
useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user = root
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password = root
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 5
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.validationQuery=select 0 from dual
```

Please help me to do that.

Comment: Quartz does not handle transactions, the application container does (Spring, EJB or whatever technology you're using). So if your transactions are rolling back then probably the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: yes spring does but how to handle it

Comment: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX:- JobStoreTX manages all transactions itself by calling commit () (or rollback ()) on the database connection after               every action (such as the addition of a job). JDBCJobStore is appropriate if you are using Quartz in a stand-alone application or within a servlet container if the application is not using JTA transactions.

Comment: can we set false to prevent rollback

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I'm having the same issues.